# Is it possible to solve a system of equations comprising FFTs?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, fast-fourier-transform

Consider the following known matrices, ***A, B, C*** and these unknown matrices ***X,Y***, all of which comprise values in $\Bbb R$. Also consider $F(x)$ as the *[*Fast Fourier Transform function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)** (the discrete version) and $F_{inverse}(x)$ as the **Inverse  Fourier Transform function** (which you might need for solving the equation below).

Can we solve for ***X*** and ***Y*** in this equation,

$$F(A) = F(B)*F(X)+F(C)*F(Y)$$

where **' $*$ '** is the element-wise multiplication.

Comment: What is the DFT of a matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can. First isolate $F(X)$:
$$F(A) - F(C) * F(Y) = F(B) * F(X)$$
$$( 1.0 \text{./} F(B) ) * ( F(A) - F(C) * F(Y) ) = F(X)$$
where "./" represents elementwise division. Then apply the inverse transformation:
$$F_{\text{inverse}}\left( ( 1.0 \text{./} F(B) ) * ( F(A) - F(C) * F(Y) ) \right) = X$$

Comment: Thanks and sorry I might not have explained the question well.
***Y*** is another **unknown** matrix; so, In addition to ***X***, can we solve for ***Y*** too? Thanks

Comment: Well, that was a rather significant change, indeed. In that case, no. The problem is underdetermined.